# Connecting via Ethernet on second AirPort Extreme

Tags: router, ethernet, airport-extreme

Would It be possible to connec my xbox 360 to a second AirPort Extreme, wherein this AirPort Extreme is wirelessly linked to the first?

I assume it is and is straight forward, but I thought I'd ask first. Also, would an Ethernet to a second AirPort Extreme be any faster than, say, a dual band wifi connection from a MacBook? Obviously environmental factors play in, but I'm mostly curious about the relative receiving strength of the airport vs laptop.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is yes. It is possible